# How to push all git repo's from a directory to git in a shellscript

Tags: bash, git, shell, github, automation

I am trying to write a bash script that finds new repo's and files and commit & push them all, and future git repo's that i add to my projects folder.

All my git projects are stored in a folder i have on my system for simplicity.

The problem i am facing is that whenever i try and use a 1 liner to find all .git folders and run commands on them it fails to do all the 3 git commands on the folders that need it(add, commit, push)

I have tried to run different versions of the script, some with & at git push and some with && but it still only adds and commits the repo's with changes but it dont push them.

I also tried making it into a function to make it run on as an individual command but i still get error messages all over the place.

My script looks like this:

```
# Location of all my github projects
mygit=$HOME/github/myrepos

addcompush="git add . && git commit -a -m "Uploaded by script, no commit msg" & git push"

# Find all git repo folders and run git add + git commit + git push on them
find "$mygit" -name ".git" -type d -exec bash -c "echo '{}' && cd '{}'/.. && $(addcompush)" \;
```

I also tried diffrent versions of this as explained above:

```
find "$mygit" -name ".git" -type d -exec bash -c "echo '{}' && cd '{}'/.. && git add . && git commit -a -m "uploaded by script" && git push" \;
```

This does the git add and commit but it does not push them, my suspicion is that it is due to the &&. But i am totaly lost as of how to fix this.

Do i need to restructure my entire way of approaching this or can i make this work as is?

Comment: Shouldn't it be a `&&` instead of `&` right before the push?

Comment: Yea i thought so aswell, but when i tried that it would only put the files in my local repo not push them to github.

Answer (score 0):

Posting my own solution here, not the most elegant solution but it works. The way i see it atm the find command breaks if there is nothing to commit in 1 folder.

Hence i found it to be better to make a script that deals with execution in a much more straight forward way that a 1 liner.

```
# Location of the git folder collection
mygitfolder=$HOME/github/myrepos

# Loop through all folders and place the names in an array
git_folders=()
while IFS= read -r line; do
    git_folders+=( "$line" )
  done< <(ls ~/github/myrepos/)

# Loop through the array and run the commands needed to automaticly push a repo to github,
# git add, commit, push(IF commit executed sucsessfully meaning it was something to commit in that folder) 
for folder in "${git_folders[@]}"
do
   cd "$mygitfolder/$folder"; printf "\n\nChecking the $folder repo "
   git add .
   git commit -a -m "Uploaded by script, no commit msg added"
   if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
     git push
   fi
done
```